# Noun+adj phrase

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning and grammatical structure of bold part? Is there any easier paraphrase?

> The vast majority of F5 mirror neurons shows a marked similarity between
>   the **action effective** when observed and the **action effective** when executed.

Stamenov, M., & Gallese, V. (Eds.). (2002). *Mirror neurons and the evolution of brain and language* (Vol. 42). John Benjamins Publishing.‏

Comment: I think there may be a translation issue. But I am not sure. I'm pretty sure it should be: effective action. Those guys were the editors but one is Italian and the other appears to be Slavic [?].

Comment: Check this out: mirror neurons + effective action: https://www.google.com/search?ei=_gvVWpvcMqny5gLHgLy4Bg&q=mirror+neurons+++%2B+%22effective+action%22&oq=mirror+neurons+++%2B+%22effective+action%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...8599.18437.0.18737.30.21.9.0.0.0.85.1492.21.21.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.158...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.UeYFC_RoOVc

Comment: effective action + Gallese, properly translated: http://old.unipr.it/arpa/mirror/pubs/pdffiles/Gallese/keysersetal2003.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the word "effective" and it immediately becomes easier to understand.

The phrase "action effective" appears to be technical jargon or a term of art that is presumed to be understood by a reader well-versed in experimental neuroscience. The action effective is either what the monkey does or what it watches another monkey do. For ordinary mortals it's just the action.

Comment: It should be effective action. I don't think one can just scrap words like that....

Comment: @Lambie, I hear you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little odd, but I think the intention here is a reduced relative clause. That is you should understand this to mean

> ...the action *that was* effective when observed and the action *that was* effective when executed.